# Error in SQLite on NHibernate upgrade (2 to 3)

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite

When I upgraded my NHibernate from 2 to 3, my SQLite tem database showed a error:

Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "System.Data.SQLite.SR.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "System.Data.SQLite" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

The project using SQL Server work fine, but the test project using SQLite show this error.

Any solution?

My CFG:

```
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name='proxyfactory.factory_class'>NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver</property>`
```

Tks[]

Patrick Coelho

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you found a solution already. But I ran into the same problem. This setting (using Fluent Nh config) solved it for me:

```
.Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().Raw("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none").ShowSql())
```

It's the 'raw' thing that does the magic. I got it from this post: [NHibernate on SQLite 3.0 – a workaround for “Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture”](http://mystuffisallhere.com/blog/post/2009/06/29/NHibernate-on-SQLite-30-e28093-a-workaround-for-e2809cCould-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culturee2809d.aspx)